# Opening multiple windows in e4 locks previous windows

Tags: java, swt, rcp, e4

I am building an application with E4 and SWT . For a button click, sometimes a new window(shell) is opened. The problem is when I open a new window, I am unable to use the other windows, in a sense, it's getting locked. Unless I close the latest window, cannot access the others. This makes debugging a little difficult. I am not sure if this is due to e4 model or SWT framework.
Could you please tell me why this is and how to overcome this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show us the code that creates and opens the window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what was wrong.
The shell creation was wrong because I was using APPLICATION_MODAL bit:

```
shell = new Shell(Display.getCurrent(), SWT.TITLE | SWT.CLOSE | SWT.MAX | SWT.SHELL_TRIM | SWT.APPLICATION_MODAL | SWT.YES | SWT.NO);
```

It had to be PRIMARY_MODAL:

```
shell = new Shell(Display.getCurrent(), SWT.TITLE | SWT.CLOSE | SWT.MAX | SWT.SHELL_TRIM | SWT.PRIMARY_MODAL | SWT.YES | SWT.NO);
```

Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

I have run into this issue before as I was creating a new window (`MWindow`) and adding it to a perpective (`MPerspective`). If this is what you are doing then you have two options:

1. Add the new window to the application (`MApplication`) instead of the perspective
2. Add the tag `IPresentationEngine.WINDOW_TOP_LEVEL` to the new window. (For more Information see: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=441251)

Additional Information to (2): If you also want your window to be minimizable and to have an icon representation in the windows task bar you can use the following setting to configure the renderer

```java
MWindow window = modelService.createModelElement(MTrimmedWindow.class);
window.getTags().add(IPresentationEngine.WINDOW_TOP_LEVEL);         
window.getPersistedState().put(IPresentationEngine.STYLE_OVERRIDE_KEY, "" + SWT.SHELL_TRIM);
```

Comment: Hi ... I have created the main model , that is parts,for the UI using e4.xmiLike this - In the e4.xmi -> Windows -> TrimmedWindow-> Controls->PerspectiveStack->Perspective->Controls->PartSashContainer ->PartStack -> Part . This part has an associated class in which have a SWT shell and fill up the shell with different components. I have not used explicitly MWindow or MPerspective.

Comment: Ok. In that case, your issue is probably unconnected to e4. You should add your comment to your question. Making your question clearer to others will increase your chance to get a good answer. Also, please show the code that includes the call to "new Shell(...)" etc.

Comment: Hi .. You were right. It was the shell creation which was wrong. Previously  was creating shell using SWT.APPLICATION_MODAL, changed to SWT.PRIMARY_MODAL. Works fine now.
Thanks for you help.